# Committing code in a class is showing "The type has NCSS line count of 1200. But the class already had around 2000 lines of code till now

Tags: java, pmd

After adding 2 lines  and making minor changes in an if condition of a method,
I tried committing the code and got the NCSS line count error.

I tried reducing the line count of the method but removing few other lines which could be removed. I still got the same error.

After moving this if condition alone to a different class, which also has equal number of lines as the first class, both the first and the second class got committed however.

Could anyone tell me what was wrong here?

Comment: I have gone through that already. What I understood is that we should split it up if it exceeds the limit. I understand that. We usually do it. But in this case, removing equal or more  number of lines as the new number of lines I added dint help. If it was a line count issue, this approach should have helped.

Comment: btw I think it has nothing to do with SVN.  The tag LOC is also confusing here.  You've better find out what tool is responsible for such kind of checking (PMD maybe?) else I believe it will be considered off topic in StackOverflow

Comment: what is "this if condition"? I wish everyone have a crystal ball to see your code...  I read your question 3 times and still don't understand what you are asking, and what you have encountered

Comment: The class has more than 2000 lines already. Till now, there have been no ncss errors. Today when I made few changes to a method in the class, which added 1 or 2 lines, the above mentioned ncss error came.

Comment: I tried removing an equal number of lines from this code to check if it is an issue of the code crossing the limit by few lines. But even after removing those few lines, it gave the same error.

Comment: Then I tried to move this newly added code to a different class(this class has more lines of code than the first one). This time though we expect NCSS error, it doesn't show up. So how can it be an issue with the lines of code in the class.